# Google Sheets - Compare multiple words in cell with another cell & count number of matches

Tags: google-sheets, compare, substring, match

If cell A1 contains "Brother Sister Father Mother Grandson" and cell A2 contains "Mother Father", return 2 in cell A3.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," "))=SPLIT(A2," "))
```

Comment: Interesting that this solution is not case sensitive while the other response (as written) is.

Answer (score 1):

For the giving example, this formula entered in A3 should work

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(split(A1, " "), substitute(A2, " ", "|"))))
```

All depends on how the "real data" is structured.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1;" "))=SPLIT(A2;" "))
```